# Running recursive query in Vertica

Tags: sql, recursive-query, vertica

I am trying to do the exact same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191937/counting-sequential-events-and-counts-of-sequences-sql). But I am in Vertica, and I am finding no way to carry out the top answer, or the other answers. So basically I have tried **connect by** and sub query **UNION ALL** method, and I don't think Vertica supports it.

Is there any way I can replicate the solution in Vertica?

EDIT: Full Question

I am trying to calculate 30-day readmission chains, which is a sequence of readmissions within 30 days from its previous admission. The following data shows a simplified situation where we have events, rather than admission and discharges. Difference in days between events will identify it as a 30-day readmission, consecutive 30 day readmissions(Chain Len) will be a single chain of readmission (Count).

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Events (
    EventID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    EventDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PersonID INT NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT dbo.Events (EventDate, PersonID)
VALUES 
    ('2014-01-01', 1), ('2014-01-05', 1), ('2014-02-02', 1), ('2014-03-30', 1), ('2014-04-04', 1), 
    ('2014-01-11', 2), ('2014-02-02', 2),
    ('2014-01-03', 3), ('2014-03-03', 3);
GO
```

Sample Output

```
EventID EventDate  PersonID CHAIN LEN Count
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
1       2014-01-01 1        1         1
2       2014-01-05 1        2         1
3       2014-02-02 1        3         1
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
4       2014-03-30 1        1         2
5       2014-04-04 1        2         2
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
6       2014-01-11 2        1         1
7       2014-02-02 2        2         1
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
8       2014-01-03 3        1         1
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
9       2014-03-03 3        1         2
------- ---------- -------- --------- -----
```

Comment: I would suggest that you provide sample data and desired results in the query that you are asking, rather than relying on another rather complicated question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your comment. I have updated the question.

Comment: What is "vertica" and how is it related to Oracle? (Or - is it?) Does an Oracle SQL solution help? If not, the `oracle` tag at the bottom of your question should probably be removed.

Comment: @mathguy Vertica is a columnar RDBMS. I am unsure if Oracle SQL solution helps or not, hence I kept the tags so that people with expertise in either might be able to help me.

Comment: OK, it seems (from a quick google search) that vertica supports analytic functions, and I assume it should support subqueries... I will post an Oracle solution, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Oracle solution; see if it works. You may need to make some changes for vertica, as each db dialect has its own quirks. Vertica does support analytic functions, which is the main ingredient.

The method used here is a very well known one, it is usually called "start-of-groups" method (for the "flags" created in the innermost subquery).

```
select eventid, eventdate, personid,
       row_number() over 
         (partition by personid, ct order by eventdate) as chain_len,
       ct
from   (
         select eventid, eventdate, personid,
                count(flag) over 
                  (partition by personid order by eventdate) + 1 as ct
         from   (
                  select eventid, eventdate, personid,
                         case when eventdate > lag(eventdate) over 
                              (partition by personid order by eventdate) + 30  
                              then 0 end as flag
                  from   events
                )
       )
order by personid, eventdate  -- if needed
;
```

Comment: I have access to a subset of my data at this time, and your work code works like a charm. I will run it on the full dataset tomorrow morning and let you know. But I see no reason why it won't. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. May I ask another question in lieu of the above one here?

Comment: @FightMilk - You may ask another question; but if it is different from the above one, you should open a new thread.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so!