# Mapping to first parent case for many sequential child cases in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table of cases which are field service requests for maintenance. There are times when service requests are related to an initial service request in the data. For example I may have service request 1 as the initial request that could not be completed for whatever reason.

I then have a service request 2 created in the data that maps to request 1 and so on with request 3, 4, 5 etc...

My data contains the following:

SR_Number  (Current service request number)

Continuation_Flag = Y/N (Y means that this is a continuation of a previous SR_Number, N means its the original request)

Parent_SR_Number = maps to the previous (Not original/first) SR_number

The SR_Numbers > Parent_SR_Number are sequential, meaning that I would never have SR_Numbers sharing the same Parent_SR_Number. For example:

Here's a visual example:

**Last Case**

SR_NUMBER: 2-6995802729

PARENT_SR_NUMBER:   2-6990314369

CONTINUATION_FLAG: Y

**Second Case:**

SR_NUMBER: 2-6990314369

PARENT_SR_NUMBER:   2-6987219482

CONTINUATION_FLAG: Y

**First Case:**

SR_NUMBER: 2-6987219482

PARENT_SR_NUMBER:

CONTINUATION_FLAG: N

I want to create a table which tells me the following:

SR_Number (SR_Number = 2-6995802729)

First_Parent_SR_Number (SR_Number = 2-6987219482)

For scenarios where I have multiple service requests created after the initial request. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Preferably in Vertica SQL.

Comment: Sample data would help.

Comment: @Serg edited above post with sample data

Comment: Research SQL recursion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running recursive query in Vertica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974161/running-recursive-query-in-vertica)

Comment: Looks like Vertica supports recursive CTE. https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/Queries/Subqueries/WithClauseRecursion.htm This is definetly the way to go.